# ROS Answers SE migration: Pycryptodome

Tags: ros-melodic, debian

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm following an instruction manual, which uses

> rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src --os=debian:stretch --rosdistro melodic

One of the commands it tries to execute is

> apt-get install python-pycrptodome

This returns the error

> E: Unable to locate package python-pycryptodome

Which, as far as I know, is because pycryptodome can only be installed using pip.
Is there a way to delete or skip this single command in the install chain, as I have already installed pycryptodome (3.9.7) manually?

I'm using a Debian 9.12 stretch VM.
Also the warning

> ROS_PYTHON_VERSION is unset. Defaulting to 2

should be no problem, as python 2.7.13 is installed.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/348170/pycryptodome/) by [lukasjani](https://answers.ros.org/users/53140/lukasjani/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2020-04-02

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-04-02**:\

> I'm following an instruction manual, [..]

please always be specific: *which* instructions are you following?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

According to [packages.debian.org](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=python-pycryptodome), `python-pycryptodome` is available starting in `stretch-backports`, and fully in `buster`. In Ubuntu it's available starting with `bionic` ([here](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=python-pycryptodome)).

Debian 9.12 would be Stretch. So it should at least be available in the backports repository.

If you don't want to use that, you could append `--skip-keys="python-pycryptodome"` to the `rosdep` invocation.

---

Edit: I just checked, and it seems [ros/rosdistro#22011](https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/pull/22011) added `pycryptodome` to the `rosdep` DB. @Dirk Thomas comments there:

> On Debian Stretch the package is only available when using `stretch-backports`: [..]

and:

> We imported the package for Debian Stretch from the backports repo into the ROS repos: [ros-infrastructure/reprepro-updater#69](https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/reprepro-updater/pull/69).

This seems to imply that if:

- you have `packages.ros.org` configured as an `apt` repository on your system, and
- you run one of the architectures for which the package has been imported

you should be able to resolve the `python-pycryptodome` dependency using `apt`.

Do you have the ROS repositories configured? What is the output of `apt-cache policy python-pycryptodome`?

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2020-04-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-04-02**:
So what did you end up doing?